# Can't update with conan lock install

Tags: conan

Another team started distributing its binaries via conan lockfiles. I used conan lock install to install their binaries. Now after a version update I'm facing the issue that this fails.

`conan lock install -g cmake_find_package conan.lock`

leads to the following error:

```
ERROR: xxxxxxxxxxxx: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at '/home/USER/.conan/xxxxxxxxxxxx/conanfile.py': The 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' revision recipe in the local cache doesn't match the requested 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Use '--update' to check in the remote.
```

Now I would like to just follow these instructions, but

`conan lock install -g cmake_find_package --update conan.lock`

Leads to

```
usage: conan lock [-h]
                  {update,build-order,clean-modified,install,create,bundle}
                  ...
conan lock: error: unrecognized arguments: --update
ERROR: Exiting with code: 2
```

I also tried conan lock update, but that asks for an old and new lockfile. I don't want to introduce a dependency on sequential lockfiles here, instead I just want to install whatever is in this new lockfile.

Normal conan install has an `--update` and a `--lockfile` parameter, but these also don't work as expected.

I'm using conan version 1.42.1.

Comment: Please, specify which Conan versions are your using, including the old and new.

Comment: @uilianries I added the version (1.42.1)

Comment: Please try doing a local removal of the existing offending recipe with ``conan remove <ref>``. The problem is that the Conan 1.X cache is not multi-revision, and it has some limitations like this one.

Comment: @drodri I need caching to work though, I can't do a manual cache removal on every CI instance. And if I always empty the cache then conan is useless since it's so slow like building inside the project.

Comment: Might be worth filing an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/, but might not be fixed in 1.X, because that is already fixed in 2.0, which has already entered alpha stage (2.0.0-alpha1 already in PyPI)

Comment: Did you find a solution? Without this working I also can't use conan in the CI.